# How to write these notes?

Tags: sheet-music

[image]

I'm having trouble in the first frame. For the left hand, I want the chord C# and E to be the full duration of the frame (hence dotted half notes). But I also want to play G# twice, on the second and third beat of the first frame, but not on the first beat.

**How do I write this?** Noteworthy Composer doesn't seem to like it. I tried tieing things but it didn't work. Is there perhaps a magic way to tie a note to a rest?

BTW, yes this is Noteworthy Composer, but if you can just tell me how to write this **in normal sheet music**, I'll try to figure it out in my software. I can't remember how this is represented so I'm not even sure what to hunt for in Noteworthy. I really hope I don't hafta add another bar.

**EDIT:** Solved. The proper way is to put a rest as part of the chord, but since NC doesn't like that, I found this workaround with ties:

[image]

Of course once I played that, I realized it wasn't good and removed it in favor of more traditional left-hand. Oh well.

Comment: Btw: usually there is no bar line in the beginning of a piece. So your *second* bar would be the *first* one. Is this an oddity of the software?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Ah, I added it myself. Did not realize it shouldn't be there. It's been too long since looking at sheet music. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 'normal' sheet music, you would find a break on the first beat at the height of the following melody line. For you example, I would expect the break written between the two notes of the chord. 
Here is something similar from Chopin:
[image: Chopin Preludes op 28 XV].

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to play G on the first beat, only the 2nd and 3rd beat of the frame.

Comment: Ah, sorry I got you wrong, but the idea is the same: you would have to add a break in the first beat. I'll try to find an example and update my answer.

Comment: @DrZ214 I've updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes! That's what I imagined, a rest as part of the chord. Too bad NC won't let me do it that way, but thankfully I found a way it likes. I'll edit my OP. Very neat you found a Chopin example because he's my favorite composer. BTW does this site allow reviews? Despite huge frustration with computers, I've actually got something pretty good and promising now, but it's only just begun.

Comment: Glad this helped. Regarding the review: There was a very short discussion on [Meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/review-comment-on-this-piece-i-wrote) . The overall tone was to reject such requests. A [similar question](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33651/can-i-post-my-cover-song-here-to-get-it-reviewed) was closed.

Comment: If NC can't handle simple notation like that, time to switch to LilyPad or Sibelius

Comment: @DrZ214 for entry most notation software have a concept of "voices", which are two overlapping lines in one bar. So in voice 1 you would have the dotted half and in voice 2 you would have the rest followed by two quarter notes.

Answer (score 3):

NoteWorthy composer also allow to do that:

[image: chord]

place a quarter rest then add the two dotted half duration notes (from bottom to top) with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> then add quarter notes.

or simply copy this code and past in on your NWC staff

```
!NoteWorthyComposerClip(2.751,Single)
|RestChord|Dur:4th|Opts:Stem=Down,ArticulationsOnStem|Dur2:Half,Dotted|Pos2:-6,-1
|Note|Dur:4th|Pos:-4
|Note|Dur:4th|Pos:-4
!NoteWorthyComposerClip-End
```